# Sleep process continues after job stopped

Tags: process

Here is a small file which sleeps for 10 seconds and then echos.

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10
echo $$
```

When I execute the script with `./test` and pause after 3 seconds or so using ctrl-z, I see that the job corresponding to the execution and the process group are stopped. If I run `fg` after more than 10 seconds, however, the shell instantly echos to the terminal. Why does the sleep process continue even after I stopped the job?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you. According to your description, the echo is instantaneous, therefore the sleep does NOT continue.

Comment: Yes. You need to pause the program longer than the sleep's duration before resuming to see the behavior.

Comment: What behavior did you expect?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Suppose I paused after 3 seconds and waited for an arbitrary amount of time. Then once I run 'fg' I would expect to wait another 7 seconds before I see the echoed PID.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Ah interesting documentation. Thanks.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski but the bug mentioned in the manpage is completely unrelated to what Ian wonders about!

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the sleep process continue even after I stopped the job?

It doesn't; there's no "active" sleeping. What sleep does, underneath, is telling the operating system:

> please suspend this task, and reactivate it in 10s

So, it's not your task that counts down the seconds – it's the timer in the operating system. And that has happily continued running while you were suspending the task with ctrl-z.

This is exactly the behaviour I would expect – after all, what would be the sense in sleeping longer while being suspended? Both are states where you're not being scheduled, and "being on hold twice" isn't a thing.